# I need some help to subtract two arrays in C, not C++

Tags: c

This should be a simple task, but I just cannot do it. The program has to create a prototype function subtract that calculates the difference between two arrays and returns the result in a third array. In main, it has to pass the values of the arrays to the prototype function and than print the values of the three arrays. Here is what I did so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 10
int subtract (int [], int [], int);
int main()
{
    int x[NUM] = {1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int y[NUM] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    int result[NUM];
    int i;
    result[NUM] = subtract( x, y, NUM);

    printf("The numbers in the first array are:\n");
    for (i=0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", x[i]);
    }
    printf("The numbers in the second array are: %d\n", y[NUM]);
    for (i=0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", y[i]);
    }
    printf("The the first array subtracted from the second array is: %d\n", result[NUM]);
    for (i=0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", result[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to write `subtract`?

Comment: Terminology nit pick: you don't subtract arrays. You subtract array *elements*.

Comment: change to `void subtract (int [], int [], int [], int);`

Comment: While it is true that the OP didn't show any attempt, the core of the `subract()` function is just `for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) result[i] = x[i] - y[i];` and IMO the question is about the way the `subtract()` function could populate `result` with the results.

Comment: @Jens I dissagree. you DO subtract arrays. That is what the OP is trying to do here. Subtracting array elements has already been provided. you subtract arrays the same way you subtract a matrix. note that subtraction is not well defined for every set of arrays

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to pass the array to the function, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 10

void subtract (int *, int *, int *, int);
int main()
{
    int x[NUM] = {1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int y[NUM] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    int result[NUM];
    int i;

    subtract(x, y, result, NUM);

    printf("The numbers in the first array are\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
    printf("The numbers in the second array are\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", y[i]);
    printf("The the first array subtracted from"
        " the second array is\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    return 0;
}

void subtract(int *x, int *y, int *result, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
        result[i] = y[i] - x[i];
}
```

NOTE: The `x[NUM]` and other similar ones, are not defined because the array indexes go from `0` to `NUM - 1`, so when you try to read `x[NUM]` the program invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

If you want `subtract()` to return the "*array*", you are going to need `malloc()`, just like this

```
int *
subtract(int *x, int *y, int size)
{
    int *result;
    result = malloc(size * sizeof(*result));
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
        result[i] = y[i] - x[i];
    return result;
}
```

Then in `main()` you would just declare a pointer and use it if it's not `NULL`, and when you finish using it call `free()`

```
int 
main(void)
{
    int x[NUM] = {1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int y[NUM] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    int *result;
    int i;

    result = subtract(x, y, NUM);
    if (result == NULL)
        return -1; // Failure allocating memory    
    printf("The numbers in the first array are\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
    printf("The numbers in the second array are\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", y[i]);
    printf("The the first array subtracted from"
        " the second array is\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    free(result); // It's not strictly necessary since this is the end
                  // of the program, but you better get used to it.
    return 0;
}
```

The second solution, is not really needed in your case. It's just to show you how you can do it. The best way is the first solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works fine now. I have a long way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are very new to C.  May I suggest the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM 10
int *subtract (int x[], int y[], int size);
int main()
{
    int x[NUM] = {1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int y[NUM] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    int result[NUM];
    int *ret;
    int i;
    ret=subtract(x,y,NUM);
    if( NULL == ret )
    {
        printf("Failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy(result,ret, sizeof(int)*NUM);

    printf("The numbers in the first array are:\n");
    for (i=0; i < NUM; i++) {
        printf(" %d", x[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("The numbers in the second array are:\n");
    for (i=0; i < NUM; i++) {
        printf(" %d", y[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("The the first array subtracted from the second array is:\n");
    for (i=0; i < NUM; i++) {
        printf(" %d", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
int *subtract (int x[], int y[], int size)
{
    static int result[100];
    int ii;
    if( size > sizeof(result)/sizeof(result[0]) )
    {
        printf("Error on subtract: oversize input\n");
        return(NULL);
    }
    for(ii=0; ii<size; ii++)
    {
        result[ii]=y[ii]-x[ii];
    }
    return(result);
}
```

This is such a simple task, so badly done originally, I can't believe it was assigned in a class.

Comment: I don't like the whole code. `static int result[100]` what if `size > 100`? Yoda conditions, your coding style specially `return(result)`, FYI `return` is not a funcion.

Comment: 1. I generally consider it preferable to avoid malloc where you have to depend upon somebody else to do the free. Memory leaks are too common. 2. Yoda conditions look backwards but they have saved my bacon more than once. 3. I have been putting parens after return for so long, I can't remember why I started.  I looked at the code at the office and it looks to be about 50/50.  That is the way it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this:

```
int *subtract (int a[], int b[], int sz)
{
    int *output;
    int i;
    output = malloc(sizeof(int) * sz);
    if (output == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0 ; i < sz ; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = a[i] - b[i];
    }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    int x[NUM] = {1, 32 , 43, 45, 55, 66, 78, 658, 9, 101};
    int y[NUM] = {31, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 199, 290};
    int *result;
    int i;

    result = subtract(x, y, NUM);
    if (result == NULL)
        return -2;    
    printf("The numbers in the first array are\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", x[i]);    
    printf("The numbers in the second array are\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", y[i]);    
    printf("The the first array subtracted from"
        " the second array is\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < NUM ; i++)
        printf("%d ", result[i]);    
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

You have to remember that ever time you call the `subtract()` function it dynamically allocates memory. It is your job to free the memory when you are done.

Comment: for an approach that avoids separating malloc/free responsibility see iharob's answer

Answer (score 1):

This is something that does not make sense (in C) (for your goal).

```
result[NUM] = subtract( x, y, NUM);
```

The reason is that a function can return a *single* value, which it will assign to the `NUM` element of the `result` array. But what you want to do is to assign the difference of each element of `x` and `y` to the corresponding element of the `result` array.

One way you can do this is to pass the `result` array as a parameter to the `subtract()` function.

```
void subtract(int x[], int y[], int result[], int num);
```

Then the `subtract()` function could do something like the following:

```
void subtract(int x[], int y[], int result[], int num) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < num; ii++) {
        result[ii] = x[ii] - y[ii];
    }
}
```

You should, of course, make sure that all arrays are of the same size `NUM` so that there is no memory access errors. Then you can print all the three arrays in your `main()`.